# Advanced Filtering in Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

How can I do some processing before returning something through Tastypie for a specific user?

For example, let's say I have an app where a user has posts and can also follow other people's posts. I'd like to combine this person's posts with the posts of people they're following and return it as one array.

So let's say that in Tastypie I'd like to get the latest 20 posts from this person's timeline: I'd need to get the user, process this information and return it in JSON, but I'm not exactly sure how I'd process this and return it using Tastypie.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do more complex processing in get_object_list. It gets called before the dehydration process starts, i.e., before the JSON is created that gets passed back.

```
class PostResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Post.objects.all()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        this_users_posts = super(PostResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(user=User.objects.get(user=request.user))
        all_the_posts_this_user_follows = super(PostResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(follower=User.objects.get(user=request.user))

        return this_users_posts | all_the_posts_this_user_follows
```

You need to fix those queries so that they work for your particular case. Then the trick is to combine the two different querysets you get back by concatenating them. Using | gets their full set, using & only gets their overlap. You want the full set (unless users can also follow their own posts, then you can probably call distinct() on the resulting superset).

Comment: Cool, trying this out now. One more question: is it possible to get the user via something passed through the url? I understand basic filtering uses the URL to nab an attribute- how can I nab the user to use in the example above?

Comment: When you're using the authentication mechanics built into Django, the user is stored in the session. So you can get it from the request object that's coming through the method call. For example: .filter(author=User.objects.get(user=request.user). The request.user call gets you the user, if you're using the Django Authentication stuff as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: I meant more of a specific user, say if I wanted to pass in a username and get that user's specific posts.

Comment: That should work like this: in get_object_list, go to the request and get the parameter you want from there: user_id = int(request.GET.get('user')). Then just load that user from the database as user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id) and then do everything as shown above.